# generics interface constraint in c#

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I've written a code as below. In this code I want to put a constraint on ServiceResult and BaseService classes so that T needs to implement IBaseEntity interface.

Here is the code:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Photo : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public float FileSize { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceResult<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    public bool Succeed { get; set; }

    private T data;

    public T Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
                data = new T();

            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    public abstract ServiceResult<List<T>> GetAll();

    public abstract ServiceResult<T> GetById(int Id);
}

public class PhotoService : BaseService<Photo>
{
    public override ServiceResult<List<Photo>> GetAll()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public override ServiceResult<Photo> GetById(int Id)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In the code I get the error as below (error refers to GetAll() methods)

> Error 3   The type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' cannot be used
>   as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'FOC.Session04.ServiceResult'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'FOC.Session04.IBaseEntity'.   G:\Courses\ASP.NET MVC5\Session4
>   960803\FOC.Session04\FOC.Session04\Program.cs 55  52  FOC.Session04`

But when I remove the interface constraint IBaseEntity from ServiceResult class and let it remain after BaseService I will get no error and the code compiles without error.

Can anybody explain me why I can't add constraint after ServiceResult class?
What's the reason? Or which part of code need to be changed in order to compile error less in this case?

Thanks all

Comment: Do you not understand that `List<T>` does not implement `IBaseEntity`?

Comment: Do you actually want to return `List<ServiceResult<T>>`? Or is that nonsensical -- does the return have to be a ServiceResult of some kind?

Comment: Seems that you are assigning a list to the serviceresult T type, you should create a ServiceResultList<List<T>> class with the same constraints

Comment: you can't pass `List<T>` to `ServiceResult<T>`

Comment: @Will , I know but I can't change the implementation of List<T> to implement IBaseEntity there, Can I?

Comment: No, so you cannot use List<T>. Period. Use something else.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. The error's cause is obvious: you told the compiler you only want to allow types to be used for `T` where those types implement `IBaseEntity`. Since the .NET type `List<T>` doesn't implement that interface, you get an error. Duh. So, _why_ did you think you wouldn't? Why would you impose that constraint if you want to be able to use types other than those that meet the constraint? What is it you _actually_ want to accomplish here?

Comment: @PeterDuniho , I got my answer. It was a logical misunderstanding of my code. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want rather

```
public abstract List<ServiceResult<T>> GetAll();
```

instead of

```
public abstract ServiceResult<List<T>> GetAll();
```

`List<T>` does not even match your constraints (hence the compiler error)

Comment: This change worked without error. But actually I wanted to return ServiceResult<List<T>> which could be ServiceResult<List<Photo>> which cause Data property of ServiceResult to be a List<Photo>

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is for GetAll to return a List of ServiceResults, like so

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Photo : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public float FileSize { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceResult<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    public bool Succeed { get; set; }

    private T data;

    public T Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
                data = new T();

            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }
}


public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : class, IBaseEntity, new()
{
    public abstract List<ServiceResult<T>> GetAll();

    public abstract ServiceResult<T> GetById(int Id);
}

public class PhotoService : BaseService<Photo>
{
    public override List<ServiceResult<Photo>> GetAll()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public override ServiceResult<Photo> GetById(int Id)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a look at the source again and understood what is going on.

Putting IBaseEntity constraint on BaseService class has no problem. Because T represents a single class here (`PhotoService : BaseService<Photo>`). So T is Photo and Photo implements IBaseEntity.

But for GetAll() method in BaseService class the return type is `ServiceResult<List<T>>`. Therefore in ServiceResult class T will be something like `List<Photo>` and `List<Photo>` doesn't implement IBaseEntity. Therefore it raises an error.

Removing IBaseEntity constraint from ServiceResult class solves the problem.